# Browsing pictures albums on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, image

I would like to parse / enumerate / browse all the pictures in my iPad photo albums (camera roll / albums / PhotoStream) in Cocoa.
Is there a piece of code out there that could help me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not an answer, the the docs might be helpful:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010405-SW1

Comment: If you know that this is not answering the question, why bother posting it as an answer?